# Apollo/Graphql, Postgres - Why is this query returning null?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, apollo

[image][image]I am using apollo-graphql with postgres and now I want to be able to fetch my backend data into the apollo client. Its my first attempt at graphql and I did the following:
i.) created apollo-graphql server on localhost:4000 which also has the apollo graphql playground
ii.) Defined typeDefs and resolvers for my server
iii.) In typeDefs -> defined my schema
iv.) In resolvers -> just added a findAll Query (tried with both attributes and no parameters):

```
    Query: {
    me: () => account.findAll({attributes: ['user_id', 'username', 'email']})
}
```

v.) Then I added the postgres dbIndex I defined using sequelize ORM, into the server file (which I used in step iv above to query my db)

vi.) In my dbIndex file, I authenticate db using environment variables, get connected message, create db schema and export it.

After all these 6 steps, in apollo playground, I see null.

My list of files are below:

Server.js:

```
const {ApolloServer} = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = require('./schema');

const {account} = require('../database/dbIndex.js');

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        me: () => account.findAll()
    }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});

server.listen().then(({url}) => {
    console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

dbIndex.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

require('dotenv').config();

const sortDb = new Sequelize(
    `${process.env.DATABASE}`,
    process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    {
      dialect: 'postgres',
    },
);

sortDb
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to DB');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to DB', err);
    });

const account = sortDb.define('account', {
    user_id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
    username: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    email: {type: Sequelize.STRING}
});

module.exports.account = account;
```

schema.js

```
const {gql} = require('apollo-server');

const typeDef = gql 
`
    type Query {
        "These are the queries we define in our query type"
        me(user_id: ID): User
    }
    "How to define the structure of user? Below is an object type that does this:"
    type User {
        user_id: ID,
        username: String,
        email: String
    }
`;

module.exports = typeDef;
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findAll in sequelize return a array of rows, try findOne with specific query or findById

It return null because the properties of type User can be resolve in array.

Comment: Yes this helped a lot! findById is deprecated now (https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/commit/1bc8b0e82d4635ff22cbd4c048c042fed30a036f). I used findOne with condition and that gave me the result. Thank you so much @waynelpu. Just so somebody else might find useful, I changed my resolver as follows:  `const resolvers = {
 Query: {
  me: () => account.findOne({
   where: {
    user_id: 1111,
   },
  })
 }
};`